# How to stop an ssh server on arch linux

Tags: ssh, kill, services

When I run

```
systemctl start sshd.socket
```

on my Arch Linux machine, then log into the server from my mac, then run

```
systemctl stop sshd.socket
```

on my Arch Linux machine, nothing happens until I logout from the mac machine.  I can still edit files on the arch linux machine from my mac.  Is there any way to close the server so that my mac can't edit files, instead of waiting until I type exit on my mac (other than shutting down the Arch Linux machine)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, stopping `sshd` will prevent it from accepting any new connections, but won't kill off existing connections.  Once you've done the `stop` you then need to do something like `killall sshd`.

Comment: I always forget about `killall`, i guess it is easier to use it than finding processes by hand.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, but its sort of wierd, when I type killall sshd, it disconnects my mac from my linux, but then it gives the error sshd(606): Operation not permitted.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess you need to be root.  I didn't realize that because when I killed it non root and got the error, I tried using sudo, but it was already killed, so it gave me a not found error.

Comment: That's because there's really _two_ `sshd` processes running for each login; the privileged process running as root and then the main process running as you.  If you run `killall` as yourself then you're only allowed to kill your own process.  That's enough; the privileged process detects the other one has ended and cleans itself up.  Otherwise `sudo killall` to kill all of them.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the processes that are still running and using established socket connections.  One way to do it is:

```
lsof -i :22 |
grep -i established |
awk '{print $2}' |
while read x; do kill $x; done
```

You may need to install `lsof` since it is not by default installed on arch.